# Mootools how to execute code on complete of a tween?

Tags: mootools

I have this:

```
this.slides[this.slideIndex].set('tween', {duration: '3000'});
this.slides[this.slideIndex].tween('opacity', '1');
```

how can i for example show an alert message after the effect has completed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use

```
this.slides[this.slideIndex].set('tween', 
{
 duration: '3000',
 onComplete: function() {alert('msg');}
}

);
```

Answer (score 3):

You must use the `Chain` feature.

```
this.slides[this.slideIndex].tween('opacity', '1');
this.slides[this.slideIndex].get('tween').chain(function() {

    alert('Done...');

});
```

With `chain()` method you can chain the execution of any number of functions. See here: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Class/Class.Extras

Comment: While the accepted answer is valid, this one is a better solution for repetitive actions, such as opening/closing an accordion, because this solution does not add more tweens. Each time `element.set('tween')` is called a new tween is added to the stack and that may not be desired.